# What is the decryption key for java when key is integer in php

Tags: java, php, encryption, bouncycastle, rijndael

There is an existing  PHP system (developed by another company) which have encryption code as follows.

```
$mopen = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', 'cfb', '');
mcrypt_generic_init($mopen, keygenerator(), $iv);
$cipherText = mcrypt_generic($mopen, $imageContent);
```

In the above code, the second line, the second parameter is the key."keygenerator()"return type is int between 10-99.

> mcrypt_generic_init ( resource $td , string $key , string $iv ) : int

I have to decrypt the resulting files using java. I'm using bouncycastle library and I have to give the key as a byte array.
If "keygenerator()" generate  32 as key .how can I give it in java as a hard-coded value.
If I use the following code.

```
String key = "32";
cipher.init(cryptoType, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key.getBytes()), iv.trim().getBytes()));
```

It gives me following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key
> length not 128/160/192/224/256 bits.

Comment: "32" contains two characters. Characters contain two bytes. You therefore use an 16 bit key, which is unsupported. Note that the length depends on the default charset, however.

Comment: yes  i got that . but how to add key padding.

Comment: My fault with the last comment. It is minimum one byte but could be more depending on the charset and what character to use. You can create a padding by creating a bigger string, for example.

Comment: yes, first I have to find out  key padding use by PHP .other wise it will not be the same key.do you guys have any idea what happened within mcrypt_generic_init() in php.

Comment: An unrelated note: restricting the key to an integer makes it effectively only 32 bits long. This is much too low for anything serious.

Comment: How about printing out the key to see the real value and not assuming anything? Please edit your post and add the **key and iv** that is in use (best would be - for later compatibiity with Java code - a Base64 encoding.

Comment: _return type is an integer:_ Does `keygenerator()` return numbers or strings? With numbers, conversions (like octal/decimal, scientific notation for large numbers etc.) would have to be considered as well. It would be easier for digits (numbers as strings): PHP pads with 0 values to the required key length. MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 supports 3 key lengths 16, 24 and 32 bytes. If the key length is in between, PHP pads to the next key length with 0-values.

Comment: keygenerator() return numbers, not strings. I mean "int" as PHP manual says.

Comment: Then it would make sense to post the implementation of `keygenerator()` or at least make some specifications, e.g. about the value range.

Comment: please take it as simple.think keygenerator() return hard-coded value 32 which is an int(number).

Comment: Short integers like 32 are converted to strings without any changes. Actually, this should mean that PHP uses a 16 bytes key padded with 14 0-values for the value 32, i.e there is no difference between `$key = 32`, `$key = "32"` or `$key = "32\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`. In Java you've to use the latter, i.e. hex encoded: `33320000000000000000000000000000`. Of course, this is horribly insecure.

Comment: yes, it is insecure .but we cant do anything.it is an existing PHP system (developed by another company).we have to migrate files to our system and decrypt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` supports 16, 24 and 32 bytes keys. If the key size is in between, padding is done with 0-values until the next valid key length is reached.
If the key length is a two digits number, the next valid key size is 16 bytes, therefore padding is done with 14 0-values.
The same applies to the IV, whose length must correspond to the block size (32 bytes for Rijndael-256). If it is shorter, it is also padded with 0-values (although a warning is usually displayed here).
If the key is too long (longer than 32 bytes), it will be truncated. The same applies to the IV.

The following PHP code demonstrates this:

```
function encrypt($key, $iv){
    $mopen = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', 'cfb', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($mopen, $key, $iv);
    $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($mopen, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
    print(base64_encode($cipherText) . "\n");
}

$key = 32; // 0-padded to 16 bytes
$iv = 32;  // 0-padded to 32 bytes (Rijndael-256 blocksize), mostly a warning is displayed
encrypt($key, $iv); // Dgfd2xT2NQ1ULob3mOX+JBPQo57JUIxabtt+TX8wnzYWhKtt/6ltY2Z/yA==

$key = "32";
$iv = "32";
encrypt($key, $iv); // Dgfd2xT2NQ1ULob3mOX+JBPQo57JUIxabtt+TX8wnzYWhKtt/6ltY2Z/yA==

$key = "32\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
$iv = "32\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
encrypt($key, $iv); // Dgfd2xT2NQ1ULob3mOX+JBPQo57JUIxabtt+TX8wnzYWhKtt/6ltY2Z/yA==
```

In the Java code the *exact* key and IV size must be specified. Note that CFB is a stream cipher mode, so no padding is used. PHP applies CFB-8 (CFB in 8-bit mode), which must be specified in the Java code accordingly. The following Java/BouncyCastle code decrypts the ciphertext:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RijndaelEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CFBBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
...
String ciphertextB64 = "Dgfd2xT2NQ1ULob3mOX+JBPQo57JUIxabtt+TX8wnzYWhKtt/6ltY2Z/yA==";
byte[] ciphertext = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertextB64);
byte[] key = "32\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);         
byte[] iv = "32\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);     

BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(new CFBBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256), 8)); // CFB in 8 bit mode
CipherParameters cipherParams = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
bufferedBlockCipher.init(false, cipherParams);        

byte[] decryptedBuffer = new byte[bufferedBlockCipher.getOutputSize(ciphertext.length)];
int processed = bufferedBlockCipher.processBytes(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length, decryptedBuffer, 0);
processed += bufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(decryptedBuffer, processed);

System.out.println(new String(decryptedBuffer, 0, processed, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 0):

I accept Topaco's answer. But the way I provided the key is little different.

```
String key = "33320000000000000000000000000000";
byte[] byteKey = new BigInteger(key,16).toByteArray();
cipher.init(cryptoType, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(byteKey), iv.trim().getBytes()));
```

Comment: The encoding used  for key and IV depends on the requirements / preferences. I chose the UTF-8 encoding, because this is an easy way to illustrate the PHP key extension, which is the focus here. Instead of UTF8, of course any (desired) encoding can be used, hexadecimal (as in your code), the more efficient Base64 etc.